# Swift dateをlabelに取得する

Tags: swift

Swift dateをlabelに取得するにはどうしたらいいですか？

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "EEEEE", options: 0, locale: Locale.current)
        print(formatter.string(from: Date()))
```

ではlabelに表示されません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あなたのコードには `UILabel` が登場していませんので、ラベルに表示できないのは当然です。

`DateFormatter`は、その名前の通り、日付データをフォーマットするものです。
今回の場合は、`DateFormatter`で日付を加工し文字列を手に入れる処理となっていますね。

ラベルに表示するには、`UILabel`のインスタンスを生成し、`text`プロパティに文字列を代入することによってできます（もちろんそのラベルは見えているViewに置いてあるなどのもろもろの前提条件等もあります）。

なので、今回`DateFormatter`で手に入れた文字列を、`UILabel`の`text`プロパティに代入してお使いください。

Comment: postCeallLabelDate = formatter.string(from: Date()) で代入したところエラーになります

Comment: @poury さん `postCeallLabelDate`が何か記載されていないので、エスパーする（こちらでは推測する）しかないですが、 `postCeallLabelDate.text = formatter.string(from: Date())` するとどうでしょうか。

Comment: できました ありがとうございます

Comment: 表略したのはわかっていただけるとおもったからです

Comment: @poury さん。それは、よかったです。このサイトは推測で答えたり、相手に推測させるのは良くないとされています。必要な情報は今後、質問に書ききっていただきたく思います。よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: わかりました ありがとうございます